# iphone-sqlite manager

Tags: iphone, sqlite

i am newb in using SQLite in mobile development having experience in sql server, MySQL on web based applications.
After googling around I found sql browser and navicut to use for sqlite manager. While working on both of them, realising they are very buggy.Now i am trying Firefox SQLite plugin.Can someone please suggest good SQLite client for mac. Till your answers I am trying Firefox sqlite add-on for mac.
Thanks.

Comment: Sqlite plugin provided by Firefox is good one. I have used this plugin for all iPhone applications.

Comment: As a side note, I suggest you take a look at [ffdb](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), a nice Cocoa wrapper around sqlite. It will make your sqlite access on the iPhone much nicer to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which SQLite Manager you were mentioning, there's a Firefox add-on and a native Mac app. I've used the Mac app, [SQLiteManager](http://www.sqlabs.net/sqlitemanager.php) for a while and found that it's quick and easy to use, even if it has a few quirks. I don't think it's buggy at all. It is pricey though.

I couldn't stand the Firefox plugin (which is called SQLite Manager, with a space).

Comment: @nevanhey thanks for the reply now i am having atleast some good options for sqlite mac!can you please suggest some good tutorial/link to start databinding in iphone controls(specially pickerview,data is being bind from nsarray or database),i have found some and playing with them.

Comment: I followed the guide in Beginning iPhone Development. I'd probably suggest that you try a wrapper like FMDB (https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) from the start as SQLite is tough to learn for iPhone (it uses C function calls and is tricky to get right).

Answer (score 3):

Try [Base](http://menial.co.uk/software/base/).

> Base is an application for creating, designing, editing and browsing SQLite 3 database files. It's a proper Mac OS X application. Fast to launch, quick to get in to and get the data you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!why didn't i use firefox sqlite add on for mac!it's fast and Good gui based. I will also try base!

Comment: Base is really worth £20. SQLiteManager is good but a bit buggy and you can't reorder anything with it!

Answer (score 0):

[SQLVue](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sqlvue/id426397771?mt=12), which my company just released on the Mac App Store this week, is a lightweight SQLite development tool for Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

[SQLiteFlow](http://www.sqliteflow.com/)

Since you're using SQLite in iOS app development, I recently found SQLiteFlow is nice. And one of its outstanding feature I think is it can handle database directory changes, this really mean something when you debug your iOS app in an iOS simulator which your SQLite database directory will change every time your app launch through Xcode.